# Setting a value and checking with null not working

Tags: java

I am really confused.I need this code to check if serial has a value and if not to set the value otherwise to display that message.

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product p2 = new Product("1st", 1.15);
        p2.setSerial("1655");
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}

class Product {

    private String name;
    private String serial;
    private double price;

    public Product(String name, String serial, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        serial = null;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setSerial(String serial) {
        if (serial == null)
            this.serial = serial;

        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This item has a serial number");

    }

    public String getSerial() {
        return serial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. You are only setting the value if you pass in null. You perhaps mean `if (this.serial == null)`.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use a message box in the setter. Ideally, you shouldn't have a setter at all: initialize it only in the constructor. But if you must have the setter, throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: You should throw an Exception instead of raising a dialog box and let the caller decide what to do about it.

Comment: Don't call your parameter of function same as attribute to avoid confusion, it will be soooooooo clear after that for you, and when you'll be strong in Java you would be able to come back to same name if you mind

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (serial == null)
```

It is not unusual you are checking the parameter that passed to the method where as you have to check the class member. You have to change it to

```
if (this.serial == null)
```

You got confused because your parameter and instance member having same name.

Why are you mixing GUI with model classes ? If you are testing that is fine, but mixing model classes and GUI is not a good idea.

A note apart from that is, I can see that you are omitting {} for `if else`, don't do that. Have them. Just to avoid confusions like this.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "your parameter and instance member having same name" is not a problem per se. It's common to do this, especially in constructors. You've just got to be careful which one you refer to.